# Bootstrap panel on top of image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with Bootstrap 3 and need to make a banner inspired of [this page](https://www.thansen.dk/kundeservice/).

I have made this until now: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BVWwRp).

The picture is not responsive. I can make the picture responsive if i add the class `img-responsive` to the `img src` tag, but then [this happens](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JZWOLE).

How can I make the picture responsive, and make the box float on top of the picture on all screensizes?

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <!-- Picture Column -->
     <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
        <div>
            <img src="https://www.lollypop.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Blog_03_16_18_Photo-1-1200x400.jpg" class="img-responsive" ></img>
         </div>
     </div>
     <!-- Contact Column-->
     <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 pull-right-sm" style="padding-top: 80px;">
        <div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
             <div class="panel-heading">Contact</div>
             <div class="panel-body">Here is the contact information gonna be. There will be a telephone number, open/closing times and an e-mail.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div><!--/row-->
</div><!--/container-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added a new relative (container for image) and absolute(container for panel) div div and removed unnecessary classes.

```css
 
.abc {
  position: relative;
}
.def {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 20px;
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<head>
   <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <!-- Picture Column -->
     <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="abc">
           <img src="https://www.lollypop.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Blog_03_16_18_Photo-1-1200x400.jpg" class="img-responsive" ></img>
           <div class="def">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                 <div class="panel-heading">Contact</div>
                 <div class="panel-body">Here is the contact information gonna be. There will be a telephone number, open/closing times and an e-mail.</div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <!-- Contact Column-->
  </div>
  <!--/row-->
   </div>
   <!--/container-->
</body>
```

```css
 
.abc {
  position: relative;
}
.def {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px;
  max-width: 300px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.def {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-width: 480px;
    width: 95%;
    height: 85%;
}
.panel.panel-default .panel-heading { 
padding: 5px 15px;
}
.panel.panel-default .panel-body {
  padding: 5px;
}
img.img-responsive {
  height: 200px;
}

}
```

```html
<head>
   <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
 <!-- Picture Column -->
 <div class="col-sm-12">
<div class="abc">
   <img src="https://www.lollypop.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Blog_03_16_18_Photo-1-1200x400.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
   <div class="def">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="panel-heading">Contact</div>
         <div class="panel-body">Here is the contact information gonna be. There will be a telephone number, open/closing times and an e-mail.</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
 </div>
 <!-- Contact Column-->
  </div>
  <!--/row-->
   </div>
   <!--/container-->
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your suggestion. I can see that this almost solve my problem. When your suggestion is on mobile screensize, is it not possible to make the image bigger, instead of the box is covering the image?

I would really like it like this example:
https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo?album_id=5346292627&photo_id=500831970522

Comment: I am unable to access the link you just gave. Please update the link, I will try to look into your issue in an hour or so, as I am going on a break for sometime now. :)

Comment: Thank you a lot for your time, and sorry about the image. I uploaded the image here instead: https://pasteboard.co/Hpp30ZZ.png. As you can see the picture on the right, where I get my inspiration is high on the height, where mine is very small. Is there a Way, where I can control the height on small screeens?

I can also see that the text box is not taking `col-12`. It looks like the box is not calling any bootstrap, but manually placed. That should be possible to place it correct with bootstrap?

Comment: yeah i got now what you want . I will post here when i fix the above code accordingly. Do not have access to my pc for an hour now! Please be patient I will try my best to fix it :)

Comment: Thank you a lot @Nandita Arora Sharma. You are a nice person.

Comment: I have added anoher snippet in the same answer, please look into it now. Also your image is actually very small that causes a lot of problems. All I could manage is in the second snippet. I didnt change the first snippet so as not to lose track of what i did earlier. Let me knw if you face some other issues

Comment: Thank you a lot, yes that solves the problem. The only thing I need to figure out now, is to keep the propositions on the picture. If I set a height on 200px, then the picture will go out of propositions. The squirrel is just a testpicture, but if you see the squirrel on small screensize the propositions are stretch.

I cannot fix that with setting a width also that match the propositions?

Comment: Yeah i know that :( I added 200px height just to enlarge the image. Ideally the image itself should be such that even on small resolutions the image's height is bigger than the text.

Comment: Please accept my answer, if your query was resolved. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

add this css to your div "col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 pull-right-sm"

```
padding-top: 40px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 5%;
```

and place it like this

```
 <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
    <div>
        <img src="https://www.lollypop.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Blog_03_16_18_Photo-1-1200x400.jpg" class="img-responsive" ></img>
     </div>
     <!-- Contact Column-->
     <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 pull-right-sm" style="padding-top: 80px;">
        <div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
             <div class="panel-heading">Contact</div>
             <div class="panel-body">Here is the contact information gonna be. There will be a telephone number, open/closing times and an e-mail.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I can see that it not quite solves my problem. But thanks for your time.